# Eclipse Luna -PyDev plugin- deleting it's own exe file repeatedly

Tags: java, python, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, pydev

`Eclipse Version- eclipse-java-luna-SR1a-win32-x86_64`

`Java JDK/Jre Version- 1.8.0_31`

`Python Version- 2.7`

I use Eclipse for Python programming, using the `PyDev` Eclipse plugin and have been for close to 2 years, no updates to Java, Python or `EclipseYesterday` for no reason Eclipse crashed for the first time in 1-2 years. I attempted to restart Eclipse via the Task bar shortcut. *I received an error "The item Eclipse.exe that this shortcut refers to has been changed or removed, so this shortcut will no longer work properly. Do you want to remove this shortcut?"*??? Upon further inspection I realized that the error was correct, the `eclipse.exe` was in fact removed from my eclipse install location. "Ok...", I thought, my computer automatically backs up important data each week and the last backup was yesterday. So I restored the last version of Eclipse and attempted to start it back up, this time using the actual .exe rather than the shortcut. Nope, the exe started, I chose the work space, it crashed and then deleted the .exe... What is going on.

I then thought maybe my Java version might be corrupted (no exit code thrown by eclipse so not likely) so I restored the last version of Java, restored Eclipse and tried again. It started and ran fine. Great problem solved... This morning upon waking up I realized that eclipse started deleting it's self again... Rather than waiting 10 minutes to restore the last version I tried just grabbing the last version of the Eclipse.exe and placing it into the current version of Eclipse. The .exe continues to delete over and over again...

I have scoured Google and Stack Overflow for several hours and haven't found anyone having the same issue as me so I decided to record the absurd process and post the [video on YouTube.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zmrL1odKt-g)

Thank's in advance!

Update- Eclipse runs fine if I open the folder in SandBoxie, place the restored version of the .exe in the folder and run.

Comment: That looks like the behaviour of auto-quarantine of exe in anti virus, so if you haven't checked there, start there. As anti-virus updates all the time it could be that some new virus definition has a false positive on eclipse.exe.  Or you could have a virus? Either way, your problem sure is bizarre, good luck.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be due to my anti-virus software. I have downloaded the latest version of Eclipse (Mars) and disable my anti-virus software, same thing... Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved my issues by downloading the latest version of Eclipse and reinstalling both the Java JRE and JDK. It appears that my environment path variable was pointing to an older version of Java. This happened without my approval so the cause is still unknown. Morale of the story 'Check YES, when asked if you want to remove older versions'!!!

Comment: For future reference you can force Eclipse to use a specific JVM by editing the [eclipse.ini file](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#-vm_value:_Windows_Example)